# Is this integral inequality true?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assume $h: [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is nonnegative, continuous and $\int_0^1 h(x)\mathrm{d}x=2$. It is true that $$\int_0^x h(\tilde{x})\mathrm{d}\tilde{x}\int_x^1 h(\tilde{x})\mathrm{d}\tilde{x}\leq 2 x h(x)\quad\forall x\in[0,1]?$$ If it is not true, is there any simple sufficient condition on $h$ to guarantee this inequality?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing of note here is that $$\int_{x}^{1}h(\tilde x)\,d\tilde x = 2-\int_{0}^{x}h(\tilde x)\,d\tilde x$$
meaning, if we let $H(x)=\int_{0}^{x}h(\tilde x)\,d\tilde x$, your inequality is
$$H(x)(2-H(x))\leq 2xh(x)$$
or, equivalently
$$H(x)(2-H(x))\leq 2xH'(x)$$
since $H'=h$. Using the conditions on $h$, we can say that we wish for this to hold of any continuously differentiable, increasing function $H$ - which is clearly false. If you set $h(x)$ to something like $3-12x(1-x)$, which has a zero at $x=\frac{1}2$, but satisfies the conditions otherwise, then the statement is clearly false, as the left hand side is positive, but the right hand of the inequality would be $0$.

Moreover, requiring something like $h$ be increasing (or decreasing) would do little, since we could easily take a function like
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}1 && \text{if }x\leq\frac{1}3\\6x-1 &&\text{if }\frac{1}3<x\leq \frac{2}3 \\3&&\text{if }x>\frac{2}3\end{cases}$$
(or $h(-x)$ from above) which would be a counterexample. Neither would $h$ being symmetrical improve things (since the counterexample I gave earlier doesn't function either).

It might be helpful if you explained how you came to this inequality, because it's not clear to me why it would be expected to be true.

Comment: There's $\int_0^1 h(t)\,dt = 2$, which is $H(1) = 2$, as a premise.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, good catch; I guess in my head I figured that, as long as $\int_{0}^{1}h(t)$ wasn't $0$, I could just rescale things to make it fit the initial conditions (which isn't necessarily true). I edited the counterexamples to fit the condition, though it doesn't change the fact that they're counterexamples.